# Make centered DIV scroll when full

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with its contents in the center of the page. When the content of this DIV gets too tall, the page doesn't scroll.

```css
.page {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #E71D36;
    z-index: +999;
}

.content {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.content {
    width: 90%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
<div class="content">
<h1>Page Header</h1>
<h2>This content should scroll over the background.</h2>
<br>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque velit leo, vestibulum et massa nec, ullamcorper porta mauris. Ut sit amet fermentum lacus. Aenean convallis lectus a orci scelerisque auctor vel ac odio. Phasellus sit amet porta sem. Nunc ut felis eget ipsum tincidunt maximus eleifend fermentum velit. Pellentesque pretium erat ut placerat eleifend. Donec nulla nisl, malesuada eu ligula non, lacinia molestie augue. Donec lectus massa, eleifend et magna rutrum, bibendum sagittis ipsum. Nullam ut tellus tempus, scelerisque tellus eu, convallis tellus.
<br>
Nam rutrum ultricies faucibus. Morbi nec odio id arcu mollis dapibus. Aliquam vulputate hendrerit leo vel posuere. Pellentesque at tincidunt est. Nullam non lorem vel mi luctus tristique. Suspendisse egestas iaculis augue, vitae sollicitudin risus fringilla sit amet. Etiam ac diam in erat hendrerit feugiat vel dapibus metus. Morbi pulvinar ultricies diam, id congue nisi.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the content gets cut off. I've only just noticed this so need this to be what scrolls on the page, over the top of the page background. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Add `overflow:auto;` then center using flexbox instead of absolute position:

```css
.page {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto; /* added */
  display: flex; /* added */
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #E71D36;
  z-index: 999;
}

.content {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto; /* center */
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .content {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Page Header</h1>
    <h2>This content should scroll over the background.</h2>
    <br>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque velit leo, vestibulum et massa nec, ullamcorper porta mauris. Ut sit amet fermentum lacus. Aenean convallis lectus a orci scelerisque auctor vel ac odio. Phasellus sit amet porta
      sem. Nunc ut felis eget ipsum tincidunt maximus eleifend fermentum velit. Pellentesque pretium erat ut placerat eleifend. Donec nulla nisl, malesuada eu ligula non, lacinia molestie augue. Donec lectus massa, eleifend et magna rutrum, bibendum sagittis
      ipsum. Nullam ut tellus tempus, scelerisque tellus eu, convallis tellus.
      <br> Nam rutrum ultricies faucibus. Morbi nec odio id arcu mollis dapibus. Aliquam vulputate hendrerit leo vel posuere. Pellentesque at tincidunt est. Nullam non lorem vel mi luctus tristique. Suspendisse egestas iaculis augue, vitae sollicitudin
      risus fringilla sit amet. Etiam ac diam in erat hendrerit feugiat vel dapibus metus. Morbi pulvinar ultricies diam, id congue nisi.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the closest answer but the issue is that it extends the page rather than scrolls over the top of it.

Comment: @learningtoanimate it doesn't extend the page .. the page will remain height:100%

Comment: I've got that close to working now. Had to make some tweaks so that the content would stay centered. You removed a bit. Please see my question for updated code.

Comment: extends the page? you are using @media to change width.. if you dont want to extend the page set min-width..

Comment: @learningtoanimate I add more than overflow to my code, run the snippet and test the code.

Comment: @learningtoanimate you have to also remove position:absolute as I stated

Comment: Removing position absolute from the `content` div means it is no longer in the center of the page.

Comment: @learningtoanimate margin will center the content, run the code snippet and see the result

Comment: @learningtoanimate are you sure? you run the code on full page?

Answer (score -3):

> The overflow-y CSS property sets what shows when content overflows a
>   block-level element's top and bottom edges

```
.page{
    overflow-y: auto;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can someone explain to me the problem with this answer please?